# displaying functions as order by declaration in eclipse-project explorer

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse project explorer shows function/var declaration as this(alphabetically sorted) :

[image]

However, I want it to look as this :

[image]

which happens to be the *order of declaration* in my class.

Kindly help me in achieving this.

Comment: Do you mean the Package Explorer? The only sorting options are those shown in `Preferences > Java > Appearance > Members Sort Order`.

Comment: @greg-449 yes the first image is taken from `Package explorer` which by default appears on the left. The second image is from `Outline` which usually appears on the right.

Comment: Although outline displays them as order of declaration the PE displays alphabetical

Comment: Outline has a button in the toolbar to display sorted or not, Package Explorer does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no option to 'unsort' the package explorer view, except the one that shows public members first (Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Appearance -> Members Sort Order). I also think that this setting will be implemented soon since the following bugs are really old an have been resolved as WONTFIX.

[Bug 51611 - No option to not sort members in package explorer](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=51611)
[Bug 32930 - Unify Member Sorting [render] [browsing] [outliner] [package explorer]](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32930)

As an alternative you can use the outline or members view. There you can sort alphabetically or by declaration order using the toolbar button of the view.

I personally like the outline view more than the package explorer for member overview since I don't like it so much when the package explorer gets messed up with too much information ...